# registering Android device on WSO2-EMM 2.0.1

Tags: wso2-iot

I installed wso2-emm 2.0.1. I'm able to login and create users. When trying to add an android device, i get the error message: "cannot proceed the registration. Please contact administrator". On the server in the wso2server.log I find the following error messages:

```
[2016-05-15 10:35:12,524]  WARN -  No operation matching request path "/mdm-android-agent/operation/c8018e1e51bbc600" is found, Relative Path: /c8018e1e51bbc600, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details. {org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils}
[2016-05-15 10:35:12,526]  WARN -  javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:478)
......
```

I assume, I made a mistake when modifying config files but don't know why the request, which looks fine for me isn't working and where to start investigating...

Answer (score 1):

i finally found it:
i had enabled HTTPS in /repository/deployment/server/webapps/mdm-android-agent/WEB-INF/web.xml without modifing the android app.

commenting out the following block made it working again:

```
 <security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>MDM-Admin</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```